# Create custom JSON array in C#

Tags: asp.net, json

Hi I have a SQL Serve Stored Procedure that returns me data as follows (please see the following image).
[image]

I want to create a JSON array that should like follows -

```
blankForms = [{
                    "category":"IT Requisition",
                    "forms":[{
                                "formId":"29C37639-C4F3-4F0E-B7BD-8823B73B92A1",
                                "formName":"Employee_Details.doc",
                                "formDescription":"Employee Joining Details Form 3",
                                "contentType":"application/msword",
                                "companyId":3,
                                "lastUpdated":"2017-07-06",
                                "uploadedByUserId":"0500178"
                            },
                            {
                                "formId":"85470C02-9255-4F46-99D5-5E80DA58A026",
                                "formName":"Employee_Details.doc",
                                "formDescription":"Employee Details Form",
                                "contentType":"application/msword",
                                "companyId":3,
                                "lastUpdated":"2017-07-06",
                                "uploadedByUserId":"0500178"
                            }]
                },
                {
                    "category":"Employee Joining",
                    "forms":[{
                                "formId":"94D7A0D5-43D1-47EC-9E5D-3E9873932419",
                                "formName":"IT Info Sheet 59.pdf",
                                "formDescription":"IT Requisition Form",
                                "contentType":"application/pdf",
                                "companyId":3,
                                "lastUpdated":"2017-07-06",
                                "uploadedByUserId":"0500178"
                            }]
                }]
```

Any idea how I can do this in C#. Please suggest.

Comment: Search for topics like LINQ and JSON serialization.

Comment: @Murven - Hey bro, I am actually looking for a code snippet.

Comment: So rather that figure it out you'd rather him do your work for you?

Comment: Json.NET FTW This link should get you started on your road to JSON glory! http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm